# I need this jQuery function to loop

Tags: jquery, loops, infinite

Simple question: I need this function to loop infinitely. I've tried `setTimeout` (I added up the time for all the steps to execute).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function slideshow(){
    $('#slide1').show(500).delay(500)
      .animate({width:'240px'}).delay(500)
      .animate({height:'50px', width:'410px'}).delay(1500)
      .hide(500)
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you shouldnt be looping ready function what do you want to achieve?

Comment: you can use setInterval instead of setTimeout too

Comment: setTimeout should be used for higher precission

Comment: @kitty `setInterval` in combination with jQuery animations is not the best idea (i generally avoid using `setInterval`). The animations (including delay) are queueable, and this could lead into a growing animation queue if the interval time is chosen wrong (to small value) and you would only notice that if you look at the constantly growing memory usage.

Comment: i need this to start running onload and keep looping infinitely. for this, what would be my setTimeout value? also, setInterval messes up the order of the animation

Comment: setTimeout also messes up the order of the animation

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    function anim(){
        $('#slide1').show(500).delay(500)
        .animate({width:'240px'}).delay(500)
        .animate({height:'50px', width:'410px'}).delay(1500)
        .hide(500, function(){
            setTimeout(anim, 500)
        })
    }
    anim();
})
```

Comment: hey i tried that, it loops but messes up the order of the animation after it runs for the first time :/

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#myelem').stop().animate({ changes }, 500);
}, 1000);
```

Every second your element with animate with whatever properties you want it to. You *can* use `setTimeout`, although `setInterval` is *designed* for looping. Either works.

The key difference with my answer is the use of `stop()`. It stops the previous animation, preventing any weird double-up bugs.